# How to compile without optimizations -O0 using CMake

Tags: debugging, gdb, cmake, optimization

I am using [Scientific Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux) (SL). I am trying to compile a project that uses a bunch of C++ (.cpp) files.

In the directory `user/project/Build`, I enter `make` to compile and link all the .cpp files. I then have to go to `user/run/` and then type `./run.sh values.txt`

To debug with GDB, I have to go to `user/run` and then type `gdb ../project/Build/bin/Project` and to run, I enter `run -Project INPUT/inputfile.txt`. However, I am trying to print out the value of variable using `p variablename`.

However, I get the message `s1 = <value optimized out>`. I have done some research online, and it seems I need to compile without optimizations using `-O0` to resolve this. But where do I enter that? In the `CMakeLists`? If so, which CMakeLists? The one in `project/Build` or `project/src/project`?

Comment: Have you tried simply running cmake again with the build type set to DEBUG? e.g. (from the Build directory) `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ..`

Comment: Why wasn't this posted on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 18):

At invocation time, normally all that you need to make a debug build with CMake is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

Doing that adds the `-g` flag as can be confirmed with:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

which shows the GCC build commands as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands

`-O0` is not added by default to the `Debug` build, but `-O0` is the default `-O` value as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778538/how-many-gcc-optimization-levels-are-there and on `man gcc`, so it normally doesn't matter.

If you would really like to explicitly control the build flags for the debug you can also set them with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g -O0" \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g -O0" \
      ..
```

The default values of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` can be found as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851084/how-to-list-all-cmake-build-options-and-their-default-values with:

```
cmake -LAH .
```

which gives:

```
// Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.                                                   
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                          
// Flags used by the C compiler during DEBUG builds.                                                     
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
```

That command also shows other values of interest which clarify the default behavior across built types:

```
// Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.                               
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=                

// Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.                                       
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g             

// Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.                               
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

// Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.                                         
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG     

// Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

If `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` is not passed, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is empty, and none of the extra `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_XXX` values are added, so we end with a build without `-g`.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10, CMake 3.24.2.

Answer (score 14):

Chip's answer was helpful, however since the `SET` line overwrote `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` this removed the `-g` default which caused my executable to be built without debug info.  I needed to make a small additional modification to CMakeLists.txt in the project source directory to get an executable built with debugging info *and* `-O0` optimizations (on cmake version 2.8.12.2).

I added the following to CMakeLists.txt to add `-O0` and leave `-g` enabled:

```
# Add -O0 to remove optimizations when using gcc
IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
```

This adds the `-O0` optimization to flags already used for debug by CMake and only is included for GCC builds if you happen to be using a cross platform project.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to CMakeLists.txt (the one in the project source directory; don't touch anything in the build directory):

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0")
```

and then

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

will work.  Alternatively just add this to CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that in some tests my `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` contained some optimization option by default (i.e. `-O2`). In this case, the above suggestions to do something like `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")` resulted in `"-O2 -g -O0"` which doesn't disable optimization.

Instead, I've had success using a simple regex to replace `"-O#"` with an empty string before appending `"-O0"`.

My regex could probably use some fine tuning, but so far it seems to work well enough:

```
option(OPTIMIZE "Allow compiler optimizations.  Set to OFF to disable" ON)

if(NOT OPTIMIZE)
    string(REGEX REPLACE "(\-O[011123456789])" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "(\-O[011123456789])" "" CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")
endif()
```

Comment: Actually, `gcc` overrides previously provided flags whenever a new one is found. So, adding `-O0` after `-O2` disables optimization. Your solution produces a cleaner execution output nonetheless.